# Is there evidence in the books about Harry Potter's birthday?

Tags: harry-potter

[We](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/109601/11593) [know](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter) HP's born on [July 31](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/31_July), 1980, there's overwhelming fan-directed and [Rowling-based](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/627088387586027521) evidence, along with pretty [transparent clues](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sybill_Trelawney%27s_first_prophecy).

But then, I reread the chapter of his 11th birthday ([here is a timeline](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/source/the-harry-potter-novels/ps/ps3/)), and the text details the Dursley's trip day after day of the week, but as far as I can tell, the only absolute time frame for these events is "one day in July". There's a massive hint in the Hogwarts letter about "awaiting his owl by no later than 31 July" [which happens to be that very day], but that's no knowledge foundation either.

Is his exact birth date ever mentioned explicitly in the books?

Comment: See [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/109596/31394).

Comment: I've seen it, and couldn't find any text reference in it, so what do you mean by that ? That it might be some other year ? I'm interested in a "July 31" mention, not the year.

Comment: Doesn't the prophecy say something like "born as the seventh month dies"?

Comment: The timeline I link to also mentions the leap-day issue that technically, July 31, 1980 wasn't a Tuesday like it says in said chapter, so if you want real-world-coherence AND year-determined birthday, you have to mess with the calendar. I'm not interested in that (1980 vs 1979), only "July 31".

Comment: It does, and that's what I link to under "transparent clues". But that's not evidence (July dies anywhere from 25 to 31st if you ask me, and maybe July is not 7th month either), it's the birth date that makes the prophecy relevant, not the other way around.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor: One point of the prophecy is that it could have referred to Neville, too, who was born one day before Harry (on July 30). So “as the seventh month dies” is intentionally imprecise.

Comment: why is this question on the HNQ while the [same question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109595/when-is-harry-potters-birthday?noredirect=1&lq=1) which already has proper answers has 2 downvotes? sciFi SE is so unfair

Comment: @chirlu Are you sure? I thought Neville and Harry shared a birthday.

Comment: @user13267 *All* SEs are unfair when it comes to HNQ; it's a lottery, pretty much. Also, I suspect the older question was downvoted for being self-answered.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor: I’m not sure whether Neville’s exact birthdate is stated in the books (Dumbledore only says _born at the end of July_), but here is JKR’s word: https://web.archive.org/web/20060316221641/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=84

Comment: Flagging for closure because, well, RTFM (book instead of manual, in this case). And it's also a dupe apparently.

Comment: @TylerH "RTFM" [is not](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2400/31051) a valid [close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86043/276025) If you think it's a duplicate, then flag it as that

Comment: @JasonBaker Well, when flagging, you don't have the custom reason close option, so I had to make due. And I didn't see the duplicate until after the flag. At any rate, I flag "voted" in good faith; this question is not useful or worthwhile and harms the quality of the site as well as the network.

Comment: @TylerH Something to consider for next time, then. Of course you're welcome to flag as you like, and I don't doubt your intentions, but I wouldn't hold my breath for a question (any question, not just this one) to be closed because it's trivial to answer

Comment: @user13267 Neither of the answers on that question cite direct evidence in the books, which is what this question explicitly asks for, so it's not really a duplicate. It's true that HNQ is a bit of a lottery, though; an awkward feature of listing topics that get a lot of attention is that it tends to be self-perpetuating, so I imagine there's some "secret sauce" to the algorithm to make it more unpredictable and therefore interesting.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

### Yes

In *Philosopher's Stone*, Harry is reading the *Daily Prophet* report on the Gringott's break-in, which occurred on his birthday (bold is my emphasis, italic is from the text):

> *GRINGOTTS BREAK-IN LATEST*
>
> *Investigations continue into the break-in at Gringotts on **31 July**, widely believed to be the work of Dark wizards or witches unknown. Gringotts goblins today insisted that nothing had been taken. The vault that was searched had in fact been emptied the same day.*
>
> *[...]*
>
> "Hagrid!" said Harry, "**that Gringotts break-in happened on my birthday**! It might've been happening while we were there!"
>
> <sup>*Philosopher's Stone* Chapter 8: "The Potions Master"</sup>

Comment: Did he remark it was on his birthday in the movie too? I seem to remember that he did because reading that except reminded me of the movie scene

Comment: @Insane I don't believe so, no. But it's been a while since I saw the film, so I could be misremembering

Comment: Also the prophecy states that Voldermot's enemy will be born when the "seventh month dies/ends" (can't remember exact quote) but implying last day of July.

Comment: @Zikato See the discussion in the comments on the question for why that's insufficient. I particularly like how [chirlu puts it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135308/is-there-evidence-in-the-books-about-harry-potters-birthday/135309?noredirect=1#comment343264_135308)

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning of *Deathly Hallows* we have the following statement:

> "The Trace'll break on the thirty-first," said Harry.

On the morning of his birthday we have the following passage (my emphasis):

> "I try not to either," said Ron. **"Well, happy birthday anyway."**
>
> "Wow — that's right, I forgot! I'm seventeen!"
>
> Harry seized the wand lying beside his bed, pointed it at the cluttered desk where he had left his glasses, and said, "*Accio Glasses*!" Although they were only around a foot away, there was something immensely satisfying about seeing them zoom toward him, at least until they poked him in the eye.
>
> "Slick," snorted Ron.
>
> **Reveling in the removal of his Trace,** Harry sent Ron's possessions flying around the room, causing Pigwidgeon to wake up and flutter excitedly around his cage.

So, if the Trace breaks on the thirty-first, and the Trace breaks on Harry's birthday, the transitive property tells us that Harry's birthday must be the thirty-first.