# How long did Harry James Potter live

Tags: harry-potter

I want to know how long Harry James Potter ended up living.

Comment: Where have you looked? Have you tried to find an answer before?

Comment: He is still alive...

Answer (score 3):

Harry *James* Potter, the title character of the Harry Potter books, was born on [July 31, 1980](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/109601/20774).

The very latest canon writings set in the Harry Potter 'verse (namely Cursed Child, Part II) are [set in 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Cursed_Child#Act_One). Harry is very much alive.